# What does proper/improper stroke mean in the ICF rules?

Tags: carrom

The International Carrom Federation (ICF) rules make a lot of references to these, for example:

> 76. If a player pockets the C/M of his opponent by an **improper** stroke, the C/M so pocketed shall be deemed to have been pocketed. The Due shall be taken out for placing by the opponent and the player shall lose his turn.

Or

> 74. If a player pockets the Striker with the C/m of his opponent by a **proper** stroke, the C/m so pocketed shall be
>     deemed to have been pocketed.

In the *Interpretations* section, the Laws state:

> 2. “Proper” shall mean in accordance with the Laws, while “Improper” shall mean contrary to the Laws.

However, this is pretty vague in itself. Can someone exactly define what it means to have a proper/improper stroke?

Answer (score 2):

Proper and improper in this case just mean the stroke was following all the other rules (**proper**) or breaks one of the other rules (**improper**)

For example

> 33. The Striker shall be struck and not pushed.

Assuming all other rules were also followed, **proper** would mean this rule has been followed and the striker was struck, **improper** would mean that the striker was pushed.